# Disable spell check for single character words

Tags: spell-checking

I haven't found a way to disable spell checking for single character "words", like when you type 100k (k as in thousand) and it gets highlighted as a mistake. I already tried this:

```
syn match SingleChar '/\<\S\>' contains=@NoSpell
```

But it doesn't do a thing.

I know I could add all characters in a spell file but that seems a bit cheap and would require me to move my spell file around with me instead of just the vimrc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your problem is that `\S` matches characters in "100" also. Try `/\<\A*\a\A*\>` instead. (I'm not posting this as an answer since I haven't gotten around to testing it yet)

Comment: Hmm, I tried answering this, but for some reason `100k` does not show up as a mistake for me, even when I do `vim -u NONE`. What version of vim are you using?

Comment: I'm running 7.4.0 I get the same result as OP. I used @DJMcMayhem  suggestion `:syn match SingleChar '\<\A*\a\A*\>' contains=@NoSpell` and that worked for me.